# Null pointer exception config file

Tags: cmusphinx

I am trying to familiarize myself with Sphinx by dissecting the config file.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to compile. I did this by using the same class contents of the helloworld example, removed the config file listed and replaced it with the one shown in http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/doc-files/ConfigurationManagement.html

I am getting a null pointer exception and can't figure out why. I imported sphinx4.jar, WSJ_8gau....jar, js.jar, and jsapi.jar. I know it is reading from the config file. It was compiling correctly when I left it as

HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml").
Below is the code with the slight changes made.

```
package speechcapture;
//import edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.helloworld.HelloWorld;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;

public class capturespeech {
    public void speechtolist(String[] args){
           ConfigurationManager cm;

            if (args.length > 0) {
                cm = new ConfigurationManager(args[0]);
            } else {
                cm = new ConfigurationManager("testing.config.xml");
            }

            Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
            recognizer.allocate(); //Where error occurs

            // start the microphone or exit if the program if this is not possible
            Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
            if (!microphone.startRecording()) {
                System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
                recognizer.deallocate();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            System.out.println("Say: (Good morning | Hello) ( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | Philip | Rita | Will )");

            // loop the recognition until the program exits.
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

                Result result = recognizer.recognize();

                if (result != null) {
                    String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
                    System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + '\n');
                } else {
                    System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
                }
         }      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recognizer was null on this line:

```
        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        recognizer.allocate(); //Where error occurs
```

because component named "recognizer" was missing in the config xml file. When you update XML file check that code is in sync.

For more details see the original discussion:

https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4/thread/91efe5b7/?limit=25#52da